# Using the value found through '.contains'

Tags: c#, arrays

This is a console unit conversion program which takes in a measurement unit (such as pounds, ounces) specified by the user, followed by a second measurement unit, and finally a value to convert from one unit to the other.

```
string userUnit1, userUnit2 = "";
int userValue = 0;
```

The units that can be used are specified in a text file, the contents of which are split into a string array (called 'units') in the program. The text file also contains the 'conversion value' between the two units. In the text file, they appear like so: ounce,gram,28.0 (since there's 28 grams in one ounce, this value is also put into the array).

The units that the user enters are checked with the following snippet of code:

```
double result = 0;

if (units.Contains(userUnit1) && units.Contains(userUnit2))
{
    //??? Something like:
    //result = userValue */ value in the array element;
}
```

The basic IF statement above checks the array for the units that the user enters, and what I want to do is use the conversion value in that array element to convert the number that the user entered. How would I go about this?

EDIT: This is the code for storing the split text into the array.

```
using (read = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Sam Smith/Desktop/convert.txt"))
            {
                while (!read.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lineFromFile = read.ReadLine();
                    lineFromFile.Split(' ');

                    foreach (int i in lineFromFile)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (count % 3 == 0)
                        {
                            units.Add(lineFromFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are using the Split method incorrectly. Save the return value into an array of strings and iterate the array. And the whole function doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
String path = @"C:\Users\Sam Smith\Desktop\convert.txt";
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path)
           .Where(l => l.Contains(userUnit1) && l.Contains(userUnit2));
if(lines.Any())
{
    var unit = lines.First();
    var parts = unit.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var result = userValue * double.Parse(parts[2]);
}
```

You need a reference to the `System.Linq` namespace for  [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx). You can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to retrieve all lines in a file as `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: .Where isn't available for use, is there a particular system namespace for it?

Comment: Yes, `System.Linq` ([Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)). I feel that you must multiply the value instead(edited accordingly).

Comment: @BoggyB Add reference to System.Linq, and check out my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the IndexOf method into unit1Index and unit2Index and compare to -1 to assure they were found, or use the FirstOrDefault extension method and compare to null.

It also sounds like you should make a dictionay out of it, which would simplify this with TryGetValue.

```
var conversionsDic = File.ReadAllLines("conversions.txt")
                         .Select(l => l.Split(' '))
                         .ToDictionary(ls => ls[0] + ls[1], ls => double.Parse(ls[2]));

double conversion;
if (conversionsDic.TryGetValue(userUnit1 + userUnit2, out conversion))
{
    // use 'conversion' to do whatever
    var result = userValue * conversion;
}
```